# What happens when converting between tuple/list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, python-internals

How does python internally make the conversion when converting a tuple to a list or the other way around.

Does it "switch a flag" (now you're immutable, now you're not!) or does it iterate through the items and convert them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tuples and lists are entirely separate types; so when converting a list to a tuple or vice versa a *new* object is created and element references are copied across.

Python *does* optimise this by reaching into the internal structure of the other object; for example, `list(tupleobj)` is essentially the same thing as `list().extend(tupleobj)`, where the [`listextend` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2d8e4047c270/Objects/listobject.c#l781) then uses the Python C API function to simply copy across the references from the C array of the tuple:

```c
if (PyList_CheckExact(b) || PyTuple_CheckExact(b) || (PyObject *)self == b) {
    PyObject **src, **dest;
    b = PySequence_Fast(b, "argument must be iterable");
    if (!b)
        return NULL;
    n = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(b);
    if (n == 0) {
        /* short circuit when b is empty */
        Py_DECREF(b);
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
    m = Py_SIZE(self);
    if (list_resize(self, m + n) == -1) {
        Py_DECREF(b);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* note that we may still have self == b here for the
     * situation a.extend(a), but the following code works
     * in that case too.  Just make sure to resize self
     * before calling PySequence_Fast_ITEMS.
     */
    /* populate the end of self with b's items */
    src = PySequence_Fast_ITEMS(b);
    dest = self->ob_item + m;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        PyObject *o = src[i];
        Py_INCREF(o);
        dest[i] = o;
    }
    Py_DECREF(b);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

`PySequence_Fast_ITEMS` is a macro to access the `ob_item` array in the C struct for the tuple, and the `for` loop copies the items from that array straight over to the `self->ob_item` array (starting at offset `m`).